# Can I make logstash match the IP field to my subnet?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-forwarder

I want to check if the source ip in my logs is within my subnet and return a value true. If its not within my subnet then I want to can give out a value false.

```
filter
{
translate {
field => IP
dictionary => /path
destination => status

}
}
```

I know we can match the IP field value with the values in dictionary, but I am not sure how to do it.

Like my DC's IP's are mostly in between 172.17.2.0 to 172.17.6.255 and I am monitoring the traffic for them.
I want the logs only if IP address is not from my DC's range so that I can have check on external traffic. In other sense I want to have an eye on external traffic.

Comment: Can you give some examples to illustrate what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sure. I will elaborate my queries,

Comment: You can use this plugin: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-cidr.html. It can checks if an ip is from a network, adding a tag if it's the case. You'll be able then to discard the logs, using the presence or absence of the tag.

Comment: Or, you can use the translate filter, with in your dictionary containing all your IPs as keys and the same value for all values (for example `true`). Then, if the ip is in the dictionary you'll have the value in the field `destination`. Then you'll be able to discard the logs that have the field destination set to this value, then keeping the logs from outside your network.